# How to go from physical location to a virtual folder in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, virtual, directory

I have a file open in Visual Studio. When I hover the mouse over its tab at the top. it tells me the physical location of the file. In the solution explorer I only see virtual folders, however. I wish to quickly browse to all other files in the same project. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a plugin for that: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands